# How do I signal a thread to end properly

Tags: c++

So I'm working on a school project to simulate a real time auto-battle.
The code is like this:

```
void attack(Fighter& f1, Fighter& f2)
{
    while (!f1.is_down()&&!f2.is_down())
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(f1.get_spd())/10);
        cout << f1.get_name() << " dealt " << f2.get_dmg(f1) << " damage" << endl;
    }
    if (f2.is_down()) cout << '\t' << f2.get_name() << "is defeated" << endl;
}
```

```
void Fight::fight_start()
{
    thread f1_attack(attack, f1, f2);
    thread f2_attack(attack, f2, f1);
    f1_attack.join();
    f2_attack.join();
}
```

The fight is supposed to end when one side is defeated but they keep on fighting until both sides are down. How do I stop downed fighter from keep on fighting?

Edit: I fixed it.

Comment: Sounds like your fighters need to know if they are down and join and/or signal to the base thread so it knows who won.  Also feels potentially not thread safe on how you are handling damage.

Comment: BTW, my kanji tends to be horrible, I like the feel of your name if I am reading it right: Brave Spring Song.  That is awesome :)

Comment: So should I add a member to determined whether the fighter is down or not?

Comment: And yes you read the kanji right

Comment: You don't show the definition of `Fighter`. Are you using proper mutual exclusion in `Fighter::is_down()` and its other member functions? Because if you don't, you are in undefined-behavior-land; anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, if one thread modifies data, any readers must be synchronized somehow.  If not, your program's behaviour is not defined by the C++ standard, which is bad.

I'd argue how you are using threads here is bad in a few ways.

1. Either your access is UB, or you are using per-object locks.  The first means your program is fundamantslly broken; the second is a kind of multithreaded programming that does not compose.  (does not compose means two "correct" pieces of code, when connected, can be incorrect with regards to the problem.)
2. You are spending a thread, which are expensive, as a glorified timer.
3. You are doing unsychronized io from multiple threads.
4. Your thread code is broken even if you are mutex locking on every method.  Dead fighters can attack, for example.

What I would do here is:

Make a single scheduler.  It has a sorted deque or multimap (key is time) of tasks to do.  When you add tasks you say when you want them to pop out.  When you wait for tasks, it makes you wait until there is one whose time has come.

Maybe like this:

```
struct scheduler{
  using clock=std::chrono::steady_clock;
  using time_point=clock::time_point;
  using task=std::function<void(time_point)>;
  task pop();
  void push(time_point, task);
  void push_now(task){ push(clock::now(), std::move(task)); }
private:
  mutable std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::multimap<clock::time_point, task> queue;
};
```

Your fighters "threads" are no longer threads.

```
scheduler fight;
fight.push_now([&](auto when){
  round(fight, when, f1, f2);
});
fight.push_now([&](auto when){
  round(fight, when, f2, f1);
});
while(auto f=fight.pop()){
  f();
}
```

round might be:

```
void round(scheduler& fight, scheduler::time_point when, fighter& attacker, fighter& defender){
  if (!attacker.is_down()&&!defender.is_down()){
   std::cout<<attacker.name()<< " hits "<< defender.name() << " for " << attacker.do_dmg(defender) <<"\n";
  }
  if (defender.is_down()){
    std::cout<<defender.name()<<" defeated.";
  }
  if (attacker.is_down()){
    std::cout<<attacker.name()<<" defeated.";
  }
  if Iattacker.is_down()||defender.is_down())
    fight.push_now({});// end
  else
    fight.push(when+chrono::seconds(f1.get_spd()/10.), [&](auto when){round(fight, when, attacker, defender);});
}
```

The scheduler can be run in a thread if you want.

There are probably typos.  And you'll have to do reseach on how to use a condition variable to sleep until a time out or a notification that something new was pushed.